# Why is exact TDTSP solving much harder to do than TSP solving?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, traveling-salesman, dynamic-programming

I was thinking about exact methods for solving the [Time Dependent TSP (TDTSP)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cor.2017.06.026). Clearly, it is at least as complex as TSP because it extends TSP, but why is it for exact approaches that difficult to solve instances with a greater number of nodes? Do the bounding steps, lower or upper bound, etc., not work the same?

Comment: It depends on how you define "complex." From a computational standpoint, both are equivalent (NP-hard).

Comment: Could you add references to the exact approaches you are referring to?

Comment: Does *triangle inequality* hold true for TDTSP?

Comment: It is right that they are both NP-hard, but they do not perform equally on computational experiments. E.g. ILP approaches like (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054817301612?casa_token=e2LAf9a3gE0AAAAA:fD-HF8kbZXt-IOh7Dgjv9SZ_gMnlzmnqcSXJTRaf-SbqTtbZxJifAwAo_O6i0YbIqT1BVNkWous). The triangle equality holds true for most TDTSP benchmarks.

Comment: @Theodeo It is not clear what "but why is it for exact approaches that difficult to solve instances with a greater number of nodes?" means. Are you comparing exact vs heuristic approaches, large vs small instances, or TSP vs TDTSP instances?

Comment: Just exact approaches are considered. My question is why exact approaches are more difficult to solve. The size of the instances is just an example of it.

Comment: One of the culprits may be that the LP relaxation of TD-TSP is very weak. This may be due to the use of big-M variables in TD-TSP.